# How to make Windows 8 more like Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, microsoft-surface

How do I get rid of the start screen on a new Windows 8 laptop and make it have a start menu. I also do not want apps. What changes can I make to make it as close to Windows 7 as possible?

Comment: install StartIsBack: http://startisback.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easily by installing [StartMenu8](http://download.cnet.com/Start-Menu-8/3000-2072_4-75852660.html)

You get the start button back and Win 8 boots to desktop mode by default.
Order is restored again :)

Answer (score 4):

Return to Windows 7. You should not torture yourself to ideas that you do not want to take, or they are not needed.

Comment: I'm guessing he never upgraded and it came pre-installed as it's a new laptop.

Comment: @David Always have the right downgraded Windows. Having identified appropriate revisions can take an image of the operating system and install it. Accordingly, advance to get the drivers for the new installed system.

Comment: Downgrade rights are not automatic on every version of Windows, and they are limited as to which version you can downgrade to.  Having said that, Win8 Pro can be downgraded to Win7 Pro. [More Info](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx)

Comment: @techie007 Yes, you're right. Surprisingly, earlier, to Windows 8, you can lower the entire line of Windows. Thank you for a very important point!